# Sending email with up to four attachments

Tags: google-apps-script

The script I have created so far will email exactly four attachments. If all of the files cannot be found it will not send the email. What I would like to do is have it still send the email with only the found attachments. I am very inexperienced when it comes to writing code and would greatly appreciate any help. Please explain like you would to a small child.

Script:

```
function sendemail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Compensation Calculator");

  //Email Vars
  var recipientEmail = sheet.getRange("N2").getDisplayValues().toString();
  var emailSubject = sheet.getRange("N4").getDisplayValues().toString();

  //Attachment Vars
  var filename1= sheet.getRange("P2").getDisplayValues();
  var filename2= sheet.getRange("P3").getDisplayValues();
  var filename3= sheet.getRange("P4").getDisplayValues();
  var filename4= sheet.getRange("P5").getDisplayValues();
 
  var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename1);
  var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename2);
  var file3 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename3);
  var file4 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename4);

  //html layout
  const h1 = "";
  const h2 = "";

  const lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  const tableRangeValues = sheet.getRange(4,1,lr - 1,lc).getDisplayValues();
  
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML Table Format")
  htmlTemplate.h1 = h1;
  htmlTemplate.h2 = h2;
  htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;

  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail({
  
    to: recipientEmail,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: htmlForEmail,
    attachments: [file1.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF),file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF),file3.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF),file4.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]  
  });
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file.hasNext()` to determine whether the file exists, and push the files into a variable size array, like this:

```
  const pdfs = [];
  sheet.getRange('P2:P5').getDisplayValues().flat().forEach(filename => {
    if (filename === '') {
      return;
    }
    const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      pdfs.push(file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF));
    }
  });

  //...
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientEmail,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: htmlForEmail,
    attachments: pdfs,
  });
```